# Returning a list of functions, is this considered an OOP?

Tags: r

I learned this way from the Johns Hopkins MOOC R Programming a long time ago on Coursera. The idea was to return a list of functions that were defined in a father function's scope. For example:

```
newString <- function(s) {
    l <- nchar(s)
    return(list(
        get = function() return(s),
        len = function() return(l),
        concate = function(cat) {
            s <<- paste0(s, cat)
            l <<- nchar(s)
        },
        find = function(pattern) return(grepl(pattern, s)),
        substitute = function(pattern, sub) {
            s <<- gsub(pattern, sub, s)
            l <<- nchar(s)
        }
    ))
}
```

This function returns a list of functions/methods which can manipulate the item "s". I can "new" this "object" calling the father function:

```
my <- newString("hellow")
```

And using the "methods" with `$` just looks like OOP.

```
my$get()
# [1] "hellow"
my$len()
# [1] 6
my$substitute("w$", "")
my$get()
# [1] "hello"
my$len()
# [1] 5
my$concate(", world")
my$get()
# [1] "hello, world"
my$find("world$")
# [1] TRUE
```

To print the "object" directly, we can see it is a list of functions. And all these functions located in the same environment `0x103ca6e08`, where the item `s` was also in.

```
my
# $get
# function () 
#     return(s)
# <bytecode: 0x1099ac1e0>
#     <environment: 0x103ca6e08>
#     
# $len
# function () 
#     return(l)
# <bytecode: 0x109a58058>
#     <environment: 0x103ca6e08>
#     
# $concate
# function (cat) 
# {
#     s <<- paste0(s, cat)
#     l <<- nchar(s)
# }
# <bytecode: 0x1074fd4e8>
#     <environment: 0x103ca6e08>
#     
# $find
# function (pattern) 
#     return(grepl(pattern, s))
# <bytecode: 0x1076c8470>
#     <environment: 0x103ca6e08>
#     
# $substitute
# function (pattern, sub) 
# {
#     s <<- gsub(pattern, sub, s)
#     l <<- nchar(s)
# }
# <bytecode: 0x1077ad270>
#     <environment: 0x103ca6e08>
```

So is this style of programming (?) considered OOP or OOP-like? What is the difference of this from S3/S4?

---

Thanks to @G.Grothendieck, @r2evans and @Jozef. The demo documentation for `scoping` in R says "functions can encapsulate state information", because of the scoping rules in R. And the RC system "uses environment", so I think what I did was similar to a primitive RC system.

---

> > "An object is data with functions. A closure is a function with data." -- John D. Cook
>
> Closures get their name because they enclose the environment of the parent function and can access all its variables.

In http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures I found the most proper name for this is a **closure**.

Comment: what you did resembles [Functional Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) than anything else. Especially read the section on First-class and higher-order functions

Comment: Try `demo("scoping")`

Comment: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html contains a decent comparison of S3, S4, and RC.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck The demo shows exactly the case! Because "functions can encapsulate state information" in R, this style of programming is not actually considered "functional programming", right?

Comment: OO and functional programming don't have a single meaning but `newString` can be regarded as a class which stamps out objects such as `my`.   newString does pass around functions and that can be regarded as functional programming; on the other hand, functional programming usually is regarded as side-effect free and the `my` object can be modified which is more OO than functional.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures I found the most proper name for this usage is a closure.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do here reminds me of `reference classes` or an alternative implementation of the concept by the `R6` package - essentially trying to make a OO system similar to other "classic" OOP languages (e.g. Java):

Reference classes:

- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/versions/3.5.1/topics/ReferenceClasses

R6

- https://github.com/r-lib/R6/blob/master/README.md

For example, you could define an R6 class like so:

```
library(R6)

Person <- R6Class("Person",
  public = list(
    name = NULL,
    hair = NULL,
    initialize = function(name = NA, hair = NA) {
      self$name <- name
      self$hair <- hair
      self$greet()
    },
    set_hair = function(val) {
      self$hair <- val
    },
    greet = function() {
      cat(paste0("Hello, my name is ", self$name, ".\n"))
    }
  )
)
```

And then one can create an instance from that class:

```
ann <- Person$new("Ann", "black")
```

For a quick introduction: https://r6.r-lib.org/articles/Introduction.html